Elasticsearch wildcard query seems to be broken (somehow)
I am using Elasticsearch (v. 8.13.0) in a docker container. I found some strange issue when working with wildcard search and I need your help. Already I have about 110k documents in index. One of the field is called "sequence" and it stores amino acid sequence of the protein. In one long sequence where substirng is as follows:
LSKYGAATFTRTGKAAQVTIQSSGTFSSKFQVDNNNRLLLQQVS
I am able to find AQVTIQSSGTFSSK substring by using wildcard search.
LSKYGAATFTRTGKAAQVTIQSSGTFSSKFQVDNNNRLLLQQVS
What is strange, when I try to find AAQVTIQSSGTFSSK substring (additional A char at the beginning of the string),
elastic is not able to find it, even if it is in the original sequence:
LSKYGAATFTRTGKAAQVTIQSSGTFSSKFQVDNNNRLLLQQVS
My query is as follows:
GET /sequences_v3/_search
{
"size":1000,
  "query":
  {"wildcard":
    {"sequence":
      {
        "value": "*AAQVTIQSSGTFSSK*",
        "case_insensitive": false
      }
    }
  },
  "_source":true
}

It could be awesome to have some help and support from anybody!
Thank you in advance!
I tried examples of solving similar questions on ElasticSearch froum, Stackoverflow etc.

Hi which tokenizer do you use to tokenize these sequences during indexing? n-gram?  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html
what is the type of the field sequence? keyword? One side note: documentation says we should avoid using leading wildcards: "Avoid beginning patterns with * or ?. This can increase the iterations needed to find matching terms and slow search performance." https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Hi! Yes, I am using n-gram with min_gram 5 and max_gram 50. Type of the field is text.

To be more specific:
{
"sequences_v3": {
"mappings": {
"sequence": {
"full_name": "sequence",
"mapping": {
"sequence": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}

I had also a similar issue for finding longer words. It ended up that we had a longer min_gram. So you may try to reduce your min_gram to 2 or 3 to test. Or you can use analyzer api of elasticsearch and go to kibana dev console to check how it is tokenized. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html
